Github Copilot: Visual Studio Code plugin: /fix always show changes
For the Visual Studio Code Plugin: GitHub Copilot v1.208.0 :
Does anybody know a way to always show changes by default when using the /fix command?
I'm looking for a way to activate this button by default:

I could not find anything in plugin settings/advanced settings so far.

While this isn't exactly what we're both looking for, it is pretty close:

Click the Configure Inline Chat btn


Change the accessible diff view to ON




thank you! that was the functionality I was looking for!
